# Cross-compile Windows binaries on Linux using Clang

Tags: linux, windows, clang, cross-compiling

I know clang works on both Linux and Windows (kinda).

Does there exist a project like Mingw for Clang?

Edit: I am using only standard c++11 library functions.

Comment: The issue in not the compiler, its the libraries.  If you are trying to compile win32 code on linux, then you need to find replacements for the win32 calls.

Comment: @woolstar I am writing cross-platform c++11 code which uses only standard libraries.

Comment: It looks like you are right on the bleeding edge with this.  They are starting to release alpha grade tools to do that.  [llvm-toolchain-on-windows](http://blog.llvm.org/2013/09/a-path-forward-for-llvm-toolchain-on.html)

Comment: ^ that post has somebody's hand-rolled cross-compiling driver. I am trying it out now.